# Android BroadcastReceiver not working on Android 7.0

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Code is working on Android 5,6 and 8.1. Just not on my Moto G5 Plus (7.0) test device. A bit confused.

```
public void startEMAAlarm(){
    Log.d(TAG, "startEMAAlarm: in start ema alarm");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long when = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EMAAlarmReciever.class);
    startEMAIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 5, startEMAIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "startEMAAlarm: alarm should be set");


}
```

In my Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".EMAAlarmReciever"/>
```

When I run it, the log message in onReceive in the EMAAlarmReciever, does NOT run! It does on about 7 other phones though, however I only have one 7.0 device to test on.

I guess I must be missing something simple, just not sure what it can be. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the phone in question was a Moto G5 Plus, for some unknown reason it just took 24 hours to start working, whilst the other phones started immediately. Chalk one more problem up to random Android fragmentation.